# Kill forever-monitor background process

Tags: javascript, forever, forever-monitor

I started a Node app using forever-monitor. My forever-monitor configuration is as follows.

```
"use strict";

var forever = require("forever-monitor");

var child = new(forever.Monitor)("index.js", {
    silent: true
});

child.on("exit", function() {
    console.log("bot has exited");
});
```

It probably has started a background process but my code doesn't work as intended. How do I go and kill that process?

Comment: this wouldnt have started a process untill you start it.. `child.start(); ` add this to start the process. but good question... How do we stop the process.

Comment: @HimanshuBansal Did you figure out how to stop the process? child.stop() isnt working.

Comment: @Endemic I don't think if there is any function like `child.stop()`... If the process is running silent I generally find the process and stop through `Kill -pid` ...

Answer (score 0):

`forever stopall` should stop all processes that forever is managing.

Comment: I'm not using forever CLI. I'm using forever-monitor.

Comment: @SaifAlFalah Did you ever find the solution? I am stuck on the same problem and child.start() starts the process but child.stop() doesn't stop it.

Comment: @Endemic I don't think if there is any function like `child.stop()`... If the process is running silent I generally find the process and stop through `Kill -pid` ...